# Does adding an Active Directory admin to an Azure SQL server affect admin account

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

We currently have around 400 client databases hosted on a SQL Server in Azure. When initially setup, no Active Directory admin user was set, only a server admin and this server admin is used at the moment for all connection strings. If I were to add an Active Directory admin to the server, would this have any effect on the connection of any of the databases using the server admin? In other words, would the server admin still work fine and adding Active Directory admin not disconnect any users currently connected to the SQL server?

Comment: That depends on the authentication type you use in the connection string. I assume you use sql authentication at the moment, you can continue using that. However, you can use Active Directory Password authentication instead if you want. We have both server admin and AD admin, but we still use sql authentication with server admin credentials.

Comment: Thanks @Xiaosu. Good to know, do you know if I add AD admin to the server, will this disconnect users currently connected to the server?

Comment: It should not if your connection string is not changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, adding an Azure AD Admin won’t affect any connections using the Server Admin or any other login.

However, the recommended way applications should connect to SQL Azure databases is via contained users. Contained users do not get disconnected during failovers (geo-replication) and they travel with the databases (backups, readable copies).

Comment: I agree contained users would be better for a single database, however I need this person to be able to connect to several of the databases. So from what I read Azure AD is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, you can add one Azure AD identity on several SQL Azure servers/databases, and it should be easier to manage it compared to having the same contained user created on all databases. For example, changing password for that contained user on all databases. However, those Azure AD identities are vulnerable to be disconnected during failovers and are not available on secondary readable servers.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with [Alberto Morillo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8184139/alberto-morillo), we should connect to SQL Azure databases via contained users.

More information about contained users, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-security-config).

> By the way, when we setting up the Azure AD admin, the new admin name
>   (user or group) cannot already be present in the virtual master
>   database as a SQL Server authentication user. If present, the Azure AD
>   admin setup will fail; rolling back its creation and indicating that
>   such an admin (name) already exists. Since such a SQL Server
>   authentication user is not part of the Azure AD, any effort to connect
>   to the server using Azure AD authentication fails.

More information about provision an Azure Active Directory adminstrator for your Azure SQL server, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#provision-an-azure-active-directory-administrator-for-your-azure-sql-server).